# Linux way to amplify sound

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa

The Ubuntu sound is much quieter than Windows on the same machine.
When I use my bluetooth headphones, the sound is much quieter than from my android phone or windows.
Latest Ubuntu has some "overamplify" UI option which almost don't do change. Most other questions about sound have exactly only this answer. I didn't find a way to amplify the sound.

I know it's possible because I use ["600% Sound Volume"](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/600-sound-volume/) Firefox addon and It amplify sound significantly for web sites. But I have problem with all other Linux apps.

Comment: this will boost the volume   `pactl set-sink-volume @DEFAULT_SINK@ +5%`

Answer (score 0):

With GUI:

Go into System Settings, and Hardware > Sounds

Go to the output tab and tick the "Allow louder than 100%" checkbox.

You can now draw the output volume slider past 100%!

Comment: It's what I meant when I mentioned `Latest Ubuntu has some "overamplify" UI option which almost don't do change.` 
It changes nothing.